# How to understand javascript Generator?

Tags: javascript, generator

I have a snippet of code

```js
function* dataConsumer() {
   console.log('Started');
   console.log(`1. ${yield}`);
   console.log(`2. ${yield}`);
   return 'result';
}

let genObj = dataConsumer();
genObj.next();
```

and the running result is

```
Started
```

I don't understand why the second `console.log` can't output anything. Thanks for help.

Comment: Call `genObj.next();` again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generators are build on the top of Iterators. To understand generator, you need first to understand iterator. See the [**Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

For a one flow it runs to the nearer `yield` and terminates the function call. After it when you call again `next` it will continue from where it was terminated and works again until the nearest `yield` and when there are no `yields` or it reaches to the `return` statement, it just finishes its call.

```js
function* dataConsumer() {
  console.log('Started');
  console.log(`1. ${yield}`); // First `next` terminates before yield. Second `next` passes the value and terminates before the next yield.
  console.log(`2. ${yield}`); // Third call continues from the `yield` part and finishes the function, because we have returned
  return 'result';
}

let genObj = dataConsumer();
genObj.next();
genObj.next('yield1'); 
genObj.next('yield2');
```

You also can pass parameters to the `next` function, which will be put in the `yield` statement. Also the `next` function returns an object about the generator state with properties `value` and `done`. If function call is not finished, it returns `done` as false and at the end you can see that this is set to `true`.

```js
function* dataConsumer() {
  console.log('Started');
  const x = yield; 
  console.log(`1. ${x}`);
  console.log(`2. ${yield}`); 
  return 'result';
}

let genObj = dataConsumer();
let result = genObj.next();
console.log(result);

result = genObj.next('x is yield1'); 
console.log(result);

result = genObj.next('yield2'); 
console.log(result);

genObj.next(); // This one has nothing to do
```

As you can pass parameters to the generator each step, you also can return a value from . You need to write something similar to `return something`, just replacing `return` with `yield`.

```js
function* dataConsumer() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

let genObj = dataConsumer();
let result = genObj.next();
console.log(result);

result = genObj.next(); 
console.log(result);

result = genObj.next(); 
console.log(result);

result = genObj.next(); 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You said 'For a one flow it runs to the nearer yield and terminates the function call.', what does 'one flow' mean? And if the program would run 'the nearer yield'?

Comment: When you call `next` it is one flow. For the first time it will reach to the statement which has the `yield` part and terminates there. The next time again when you call `next` it finds where the previous call was terminated and starts from there until to the next nearest `yield`

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am very glad that could help you.